# Android L: Using MediaStyle Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

Has anyone gotten the MediaStyle cards in L to work with MediaMetadata? I have created all of the objects needed for controlling a media stream via the controller:

```
    mManager = (MediaSessionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE);
    mSession = mManager.createSession("sample session");
    mToken = mSession.getSessionToken();
    mController = MediaController.fromToken( mToken );
    mSession.addTransportControlsCallback( 
    new MediaSession.TransportControlsCallback() { etc... }
```

and have been trying to do this to add metadata to the session for displaying:

```
        mController.getTransportControls().play();
        MediaMetadata.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadata.Builder();
        metadataBuilder.putString( MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "some Artist" );
        metadataBuilder.putString( MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, "some album" );
        metadataBuilder.putString( MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "some title" );
        metadataBuilder.putBitmap( MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ART, BitmapFactory.decodeResource( this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher ) );
        metadataBuilder.putBitmap( MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, BitmapFactory.decodeResource( this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher ) );
        mSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
```

which I had assumed would place some kind of value in the content title and text part of the notification based on the documentation: http://pbz.kt.agh.edu.pl/~krusek/l-developer-preview/reference/android/app/Notification.MediaStyle.html

I am assigning the media session to the media style via its token before building and showing it:

```
        Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle();
        style.setMediaSession( mSession.getSessionToken() );

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder( this )
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(style);

        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class );

        intent.setAction( ACTION_STOP );
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
        builder.addAction( R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Play", pendingIntent );

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        notificationManager.notify( 1, builder.build() );
```

Any help on this would be appreciated, as it's the last part I need for really getting MediaStyles working, but I've tried all I could figure out from the API docs. Thanks!

Comment: Already got an answer from someone at Google. MediaMetadata isn't going to populate the notification view with data like the L preview documentation said.

Comment: @PaulRuiz MEDIA_SESSION_SERVICE is just supported for API 21 how can we use below 21. RemoteControlClient is deprecated for 21

Comment: @PaulRuiz maybe you should post your comment as an answer, clearly stating that the documentation is wrong and that we have to set meta data to the notification manually. It would also be nice if you could quote your source of information.